# Mongoose findOne by reference returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some events in the event collection and some users in the users collection.
I have a mapping of events and users in another collection. The event_id field in that collection is a reference to the event collection(ObjectId). But when I search schema using the following command I get null as a response

```
db.eventusers.findOne({event_id :'57988cd30e9811750324c080'})
```

returns `null`

on the other hand when i search using user field which is not a reference, just a string containing user id, I get the result as follows.

```
db.eventusers.findOne({user_id :"578cdcdd56eaec041b6caf3e"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57988d190e9811750324c081"),
    "created_at" : "1469615385595",
    "updated_at" : "1469615618502",
    "user_id" : "578cdcdd56eaec041b6caf3e",
    "event_id" : ObjectId("57988cd30e9811750324c080"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "invited" : false,
    "host" : true,
    "status" : -1,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found out the solution. If the field was defined in Mongoose Schema as `Schema.Types.ObjectId` then in the Query id should be ObjectId rather than String. So instead of query `{event_id :'57988cd30e9811750324c080'}` it should be `{event_id :ObjectId('57988cd30e9811750324c080')}`:

```
db.eventusers.findOne({event_id :ObjectId('57988cd30e9811750324c080')})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57988d190e9811750324c081"),
    "created_at" : "1469615385595",
    "updated_at" : "1469615618502",
    "user_id" : "578cdcdd56eaec041b6caf3e",
    "event_id" : ObjectId("57988cd30e9811750324c080"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "invited" : false,
    "host" : true,
    "status" : -1,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Explain  your answer, other users will find this confusing.